# OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (hostname was not match with the server certificate):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl

This classic error is showing up on any PDF that is downloaded.

The error is returned from any browser ( Not just IE ).

Using the gem `gem "bartt-ssl_requirement", "1.2.5", :require => "ssl_requirement"` and :

```
ssl_allowed :my_action
```

It still tries an SSL comparison.

I also tried implementing specific `request.headers` in regards to this error's familiar IE7 bug.

Otherwise, all links *and downloads of CSV's* work appropriately with the SSL cert.

Nothing has worked. I'm fairly clueless as to what to do, or what to inspect next.